# Replace pop-up with flip sink drain covers?

Tags: sink, drainage, bathroom-fixtures

I had my house replumbed to code and put new sink basins in with pop up wastes. But I find that the water drains slowly, and the brand I'm using breaks easily so that they don't click in and out. I've already replaced one, and another has broken.

Also they drain better if I remove the plug bit by unscrewing it, though but not needing to removing the whole assembly as pictured.

Would I be better off with a flip waste like this one?

[image: swivel waste]

And is there a drop in replacement?

Edit: Are there any people who can answer on the physics of these things?  It seems a circular drain with a cap on it viz. popup waste, might cause more drainage issues then a flip waste due to the symmetry?  Or is there no difference?

[image: pop-up waste]

Comment: Some things about these new flip drains; they are easily replaceable, they allow full opening of the drain if removed entirely, they eliminate linkage or cable problems. I have one in a new tub and haven't been able to use it yet, but I am eager to see how it performs.

Comment: I just need to find a supplier of one.  They used to be part of the drain, ie. you couldn't remove it fully, and only flip them, but if you can, all the better.

Comment: And looks like none of the larger companies stock them where I live so seems I'm stuck with this type of waste.  Even the salesman at the plumber's wholesale company said he had drainage problems with his too.